# Find and remove file extension from file name by regular expression in MATLAB

Tags: regex, matlab

I have some excel files with file extension of `.xls` or `.xlsx`. I want remove this file extensions from end of file names. Some of these files are`.xls` and others are`.xlsx`, So first I want find type of file excretion (`.xls` and `.xlsx` - for other processings in code) and after that remove that extension.

How can I do this with regular expression?

Thanks.

Comment: in what format is your list of file names? Did it come from `dir`? If so any reason you can't specify `*.xls*`?

Comment: But also Matlab has the [`fileparts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html) which will help here *instead*  of regex

Comment: @Dan File names are in a list box in GUI with both extensions. When I read it, the file name is a string.

Comment: And in what format were you planning on using regex on them? On individual strings? A cell array of strings? How were you going to extract the names from the GUI list box (or probably more relevant is how they are getting into that list box?). You really need to put much more detail in this question, some code would help a lot.

Comment: There isn't any problem in reading file names from list-box. Suppose that I have single string for this problem. We can expand answer to other cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd just use the `fileparts()` function.

```
[sPath, sFilename, sExt] = fileparts( sFile );
sFileBase = [ sPath, sFilename];
```

As a hint for your method, you can do `open fileparts` and look at the source code.

Let's try:

```
[sFiles, sPath] = uigetfile({'*.xls;*.xlsx','Select Excel files'; ...
                             '*.*', 'Select any file'}, ...
                            'MultiSelect', 'on');
```

and select 'Boolk1.xls', 'Book1.xlsx' and 'Book1.txt'.  sFiles is a cell array of strings, so we can do this:

```
for i = 1:length(sFiles)
    [~, sFilename, sExt] = fileparts( sFiles{i} );
    if( strcmpi( sExt, '.xls' ) )
        fprintf( '%s%s is a .xls file.\n', sFilename, sExt );
    elseif( strcmpi( sExt, '.xlsx' ) )
        fprintf( '%s%s is a .xlsx file.\n', sFilename, sExt );
    else
        fprintf( '%s%s is neither a .xls nor a .xlsx file.\n', sFilename, sExt );
    end
end
```

the result is:

```
Book1.txt is neither a .xls nor a .xlsx file.
Book1.xls is a .xls file.
Book1.xlsx is a .xlsx file.
```

(Matlab is easy!)

Comment: File names are in a list box in GUI with both extensions. When I read it, the file name is a string. Can I use this method?

Comment: @user2991243 sure you can, why not?

Comment: What is type of `Sfile`?. It should be string in my case.

Comment: @user2991243 Did you read the docs for `fileparts` that I already linked to? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html. It explicitly states that the input argument to `sFile` is a string

Comment: Thanks for tidying up my answer, Schorsh.

Comment: I checked it. that's true. Thank you for you helps.